# How to validate two data sets coming from an algorithm to check its effectiveness

Tags: dataset, data-science

I have two data sets:

**Ist (AKA "OLD") [smaller - just a sample]:**

```
Origin   | Alg.Result   | Score
Star123  | Star123      | 100
Star234  | Star200      | 90
Star421  | Star420      | 98
Star578  | Star570      | 95
...      | ...          | ...
```

**IInd (AKA "NEW") [bigger - used all real data]:**

```
Origin   | Alg.Result | Score
Star123  | Star120    | 90
Star234  | Star234    | 100
Star421  | Star423    | 98
Star578  | Star570    | 95
...      | ...        | ...
```

Those DFs are the results of two different algorithms. Let's call them "OLD" and "NEW".
The logic of those algorithms is following:

- it takes value from some table (represented in the column: 'Origin'), and tries to match this value from some different table (outcome represented as a column: Alg. Result). Plus it calculates a score of the match based on some internal logic (column: Score).

Additionally important information:

1. I DF (old) is a smaller sample
2. II DF (new) is a bigger sample
3. Values in ORIGIN are the same for both datasets, excluding the fact that the old dataset has fewer of them compared to the NEW set.
4. Values in Alg. Result can:

- be exactly the same as in Origin
- can be similar
- can be completely something else

5. In a solution where those algorithms are used, the threshold is used based on SCORE. For OLD it's a Score > 90. For the new, it's the same.

What I want to achieve is to:

1. How accurate is the new algorithm?
2. Validate how accurate is the new approach ("NEW") in matching values with Origin values.
3. What are the discrepancies between the OLD and NEW sets:

- which cases the OLD has that the NEW doesn't have
- which cases the NEW has, which the OLD doesn't have

What kind of comparison would you do to achieve those goals?

I thought about checking:

1. True positive => by taking NEW dataset with condition NEW.Origin == NEW.Alg.Result and NEW.Score == 100
2. False positive => by taking NEW dataset with condition NEW.Origin != NEW.Alg.Result and NEW.Score == 100
3. False-negative => by taking NEW dataset with condition NEW.Origin == NEW.Al.Result and NEW.Score != 100
4. I don't see a sense to count True negatives if the algorithm always generates some match. I'm not sure what this could look like.

What else you'd suggest? What to do to compare OLD and NEW values? Do you have some ideas?